# custom File filter for sftp connector in mule

Tags: regex, mule, mule-el

I am trying to use sftp inbound connetor of mule.

but I need to read only the file with specific naming convention having date(ddMMyyyy) in the middle.
fileName format : _.zip
example : test1_001_10072018_data.zip, test2_011_10072018_data.zip

I tried regex for the same.
but with regex it is working with hardcoded date.

Pls help me to pass date dynamically.

Actual code:

```
<sftp:inbound-endpoint ........>
    <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="\w+_\w+_(10072018)_\w+_\w+.zip" caseSensitive="true"/>
```

in place of "10072018" this date, I want some dynamic value

Answer (score 0):

can you try this in the pattern

```
#[function:dateStamp:ddMMyyyy]
```

Example for writting..You can do the same reading..

```
<file:outbound-endpoint path="${fileDir}" outputPattern="test_#[function:dateStamp:ddMMyyyy].zip" connector-ref="File" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
```